# QGIS Server Coordinate Switch

Tags: qgis, coordinates, windows, qgis-server

I installed QGIS Server 32 bit through OSGeo4W as a localhost service on my Windows machine as of underdarks tutorial [QGIS Server on Windows7](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/)

I do get my wms up and running but I'm a bit confused as to why it seems to swap the coordinates as shown in the pictures below.

In QGIS
[image: In QGIS]

As WMS from QGIS Server
[image: As WMS from QGIS Server]

Any clues are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS you have to set parameter `IgnoreAxisOrientation=1` when creating your WMS connection:

[image]